# códificación correcta de una imagen base64

Tags: javascript, nodejs, gps, fs

Tengo unas porciones de cadena que supongo que base64 que recibo de un GPS y es una imagen pero al concatenar y tratar de unirla no me muestra la imagen (solo mostrare 3 porciones) no se si al concatenarla lo estoy haciendo mal o hay que hacer otro tipo de conversion he tratado de validar las cadena en linea pero cuando uno las 3 cadena me da error en el símbolo "="

```
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
```

la longitud de la cadena es 684 y estoy usando este código en nodejs para guardar la imagen

```javascript
const cadena2 = "cadena base64 completa..";
// Decodificar la cadena Base64 a un Buffer
const decodedData = Buffer.from(cadena2, 'base64');
// Guardar la imagen
fs.writeFile('imagen2.jpg', base64String, { encoding: 'base64' }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log('File created');
    }
});
```

Lo más seguro que no estoy uniendo bien las parte pero si me pueden dar una luz de ayuda que si necesito hacer algo mas seria de mucha ayuda,

***NOTA: es un GPS de la marca QUECLINK***

Comment: ¿Documentación de ese GPS? ¿Seguro que es un GPS que envía fotografías? Acabo de revisar el sitio y hay varias opciones, no puedo ayudarte a más detalle por el mismo hecho que faltan detalles en la pregunta. Por otro lado, utiliza esta herramienta para que subas cualquier tipo de imagen y veas cómo es una cadena en base64: https://codebeautify.org/image-to-base64-converter te darás cuenta que termina en un `=`, si utilizas la herramienta https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter y le pones las cadenas que tienes en tu ejemplo, ninguna funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te daré un ejemplo a nivel de javascript, porque en node.js no me manejo

Me parece que te entrega varias partes de una imagen (más de 3), que van formando la imagen desde arriba hacia abajo (una especie de streaming). Debes concatenar estas partes a nivel de bytes no de string, es decir cada parte la decodificas y las vas guardando en un array que hace de buffer (le llamaré `ArrayImagen`)

En cada parte:

- Decodificas el string
- Conviertes cada carácter a su valor ASCII
- Agregas esos valores a `ArrayImagen`

```js
const image = [
//Parte 1
"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",

//Parte 2
"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",

//Parte 3
"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"];

const b64toBlob = (b64Datas, contentType='') => {
  
  const ArrayImagen = [];

  //iteramos por cada parte de la imagen
  for(let b64Data of b64Datas){

    //array de valores ASCII desde la decodificación en base64
    const codes = Array.from(atob(b64Data)).map(a=>a.charCodeAt());
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(codes);
    
    //juntamos esta parte al array general que contiene toda la imagen
    ArrayImagen.push(byteArray);
  }
    
  return new Blob(ArrayImagen, {type: contentType});

}

  
const blob = b64toBlob(image,"image/jpeg");
imagen.src  = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

//solo para obligar el render, no debería ser necesario
setTimeout(function(){ imagen.style.display="block"},100);
```

```css
img{
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
 object-fit:cover;
 border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img id="imagen"/>
```

Comment: muchas gracias eso me ayudo.!!!

Answer (score 1):

esta versión únicamente lo hago con el fin de mostrar como se puede implementar desde el backend con `node.js` guardar la imagen por si alguien mas le puede servir, lo modifiqué en base a la respuesta que me dio "Yussef"

```javascript
const fs = require('fs');

const image = [
  //Parte 1
  "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",

  //Parte 2
  "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",

  //Parte 3
  "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",
];

const b64toBlob = (b64Datas, contentType='') => {
  const ArrayImagen = [];
  // iteramos por cada parte de la imagen
  for(let b64Data of b64Datas) {
    // decodificar la cadena Base64
    const byteArray = Buffer.from(b64Data, 'base64');
    // juntamos esta parte al array general que contiene toda la imagen
    ArrayImagen.push(byteArray);
  }
  return Buffer.concat(ArrayImagen);
}

const blob = b64toBlob(image, "image/jpg");

// Especifica la ruta y el nombre de archivo donde deseas guardar la imagen
const filePath = './mi_imagen.jpg';

// Escribir el blob en un archivo
fs.writeFile(filePath, blob, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error al guardar la imagen:', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('La imagen se ha guardado correctamente en:', filePath);
});
```